# UTI's and File Extension associations

Tags: objective-c, macos, file-type, uti

In my application, I wanted to include a QuickLook plugin that reads a non-system extension other applications also use (let's use RAR for this example). I declare the extension as an `Exported UTI` in my app bundle's Info.plist like so:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <string>public.archive</string>
            <string>com.rarlab.rar-archive</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Custom RAR Archive</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.my-company.rarx-archive</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>rarx</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

And I also appropriately import the RAR UTI:

```
<key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <string>public.archive</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>RAR Archive</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>RAR</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.rarlab.rar-archive</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>rar</string>
                <string>rarx</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The RARX files never seem to get associated with my app after I run it, though. To check the association, I used `mdls` like so:

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree "/Users/Me/.../A File.rarx"
>>> kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "com.another-company.rarx-archive",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.archive"
)
```

Why isn't my UTI (`com.my-company.rarx-archive`) showing up in that list? I believe this is resulting in my Quick Look plugin not firing, as the files are associated with the `com.another-company.rarx-archive` UTI. The other app on my system is what gets used instead. Running `qlmanage` with debugging output bears this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem here is that you are trying to associate the same extension with two different UTIs, which Launch Services can't handle.    Your imported `com.rarlab.rar-archive` declaration is correct, and it assigns all files of type `rar` to `com.rarlab.rar-archive` as would be expected.

You have unnecessarily declared the Exported declaration, because it attempts to redefine the `rar` extension.   Instead of doing that, you just want to make use of the Imported declaration and use `com.rarlab-rar-archive` in your QuickLook extension to declare what it can work on.

As long as the other application doesn't declare a QuickLook extension, you should be fine declaring this pairing and having it work.   However, since it sounds like the other app already has a QuickLook extension for this particular UTI, I think you may be stuck with the option of deleting it.    My experience has been that conflicting QuickLook extensions are first-come, first-served.